# Laravel - Session not transmitted

Tags: php, laravel

Why is the new session not being transmitted ?

```
class RandomController extends Controller
{
    public function one(Request $request) {
        $request->session()->put('game_token', csrf_token());
        // dd($request->session()->all() : 'game_token' is in.
        return redirect('/two');
    }

    public function two(Request $request) {
        dd($request->session()->all());
        return;
    }
}
```

(The dd don't show the new session)

I'm under Laravel 5.4, and the web middleware is apply on this controller.

Comment: Are you getting data in $request->session()->get('game_token'); in method two() ?

Comment: No neither (session()->all() show all the sessions so...)

Comment: give static string or integer instead of csrf_token() and check

Comment: Same, I edit the post (precise that game_token is add in the first but not transmitted into the second)

Comment: In Kernel.php, is  Sessions middleware included before your custom middleware?

Comment: Actually, I did not add any middleware for now...

Answer (score 0):

There is one more alternative,

> I am manipulating session at global level using session helper,

Write this in method one()

```
 session(['game_token' => csrf_token()]);
```

Write this in method two()

```
   $value = session('game_token');
```

Check if its working.

Comment: Are you resetting session somewhere